# Powerball number generator

Tags: python-2.7

To win the Powerball lottery (an extremely unlikely event so don't waste your time) you have to pick six numbers correctly. The first five numbers are drawn from a drum containing 53 balls and the sixth is drawn from a drum containing 42 balls. The chances of doing this are 1 in 120,526,770.

The output needs to be in the form:

Official (but fruitless) Powerball number generator

How many sets of numbers? 3

Your numbers:  3 12 14 26 47       Powerball:  2
Your numbers:  1  4 31 34 51       Powerball: 17
Your numbers: 10 12 49 50 53       Powerball: 35

```
import random

#Powerball

print "Offical Powerball number generaor"

x = int(raw_input("How many sets of numbers? "))


z = range(1,42)
z1 = random.choice(z)

def list1():
    l1=[]
    n=1
    while n<=5:
        y = range(1,53)
        y1 = random.choice(y)
        l1.append(y1)
        n +=1
    print sorted(l1)

i=1
while i<=x:
#    print "Your numbers: " + list1() +  "Powerball: "+ str(z1)

     print list1()

raw_input("Press<enter>")
```

My code's output goes on a infinite loop. I have to kill it. And the message is:

```
None     
[2, 7, 22, 33, 42]      
None      
[15, 19, 19, 26, 48]      
None      
[1, 5, 7, 26, 41]     
None     
[7, 42, 42, 42, 51]     
None    
..... etc ....
```

Comment: You're not incrementing the value if `i` in your output loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while i<=x:` - you never increment `i`, so it is stuck in your last loop...

To avoid such things and remove the noise of `i+=1` lines in your code I suggest using `for` loops `for i in range(x)` and `for n in range(5)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. And now this part of my program doesn't work: " print "Your numbers: " + list1() +  "Powerball: "+ str(z1)". the error:  "temp4.py", line 23, in <module>
    print "Your numbers: " + list1() +  "Powerball: "+ str(z1)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: @Shandeep Plus is concatenating strings here. list1() is not a string and so interpreter has no idea what do you want to do adding a list to a string. You would want to convert the things you'd like to print to a string format.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, the following expression can replace list1:

```
[random.choice(range(1,53)) for x in xrange(5)]
```

At least, that does the same as your code.  But what you probably really want (to avoid the same ball being chosen twice) is:

```
random.sample( range(1,53), 5 )
```

Comment: I used : i = [random.choice(range(1,53) for x in range(5))]
print sorted(i)
But I got the error:ile "temp4.py", line 11, in <module>
    i = [random.choice(range(1,53) for x in range(5))]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()